# MySQL how to get 2nd most recent record in linked table in search query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb-10.1

I have a MySQL DB with two linked tables Products and Price History. They are linked by a productID field. Each time the price of a product changes I create a new history record. The latest history record for a product has the most current price. I also store the current price in the product table. I want to run a report where I can retrieve the 2nd last price history record so I can compare the current and last price. I tried the sql query below and that returns the latest price history record i.e current price. How can I get the 2nd most recent price history record? The historyID will be higher for newer records as it is Auto Increment and price history updateTime will be more recent for newer records also so that could be a way to sort.  Thanks!

```
SELECT 
  product.code, product.currentPrice, priceHistory.price, 
  product.url, product.manuID, product.lastSeenTime,
  priceHistory.updateTime, product.dateAdded, 
  priceHistory.historyID 
FROM product, priceHistory 
WHERE product.idProduct = priceHistory.productID 
GROUP BY priceHistory.productID 
HAVING count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY `product`.`lastSeenTime` DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign numbering to rows according to any ordering on the fly. Once you do that, then you can simply filter by that number.

For example:

```
with
h as (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by productid order by updatetime desc) as rn
  from pricehistory
)
select
  p.code,
  p.currentprice,
  h.price,
  p.url,
  p.manuid,
  p.lastseentime,
  h.updatetime,
  p.dateadded,
  h.historyid
from product p
left join h on h.productid = p.productid and h.rn = 2
```

**EDIT**:

If you cannot use CTEs, then you can rewrite the query by using a table expression, as in:

```
select
  p.code,
  p.currentprice,
  h.price,
  p.url,
  p.manuid,
  p.lastseentime,
  h.updatetime,
  p.dateadded,
  h.historyid
from product p
left join (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by productid order by updatetime desc) as rn
  from pricehistory
) h on h.productid = p.productid and h.rn = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using MariaDB 10.1 which doesn't appear to support 'with' . Is there a way to achieve the same result another way? I will be upgrading  to 10.2 which does support 'with' once i've tested it doesn't break anything.

Comment: Added extra solution without the use of CTEs.

Comment: Thank you, when I run the non CTE code I get the error.
"#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias" . Should there be another "as" in there somewhere?

Comment: Forgot the `h` in the last line. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you Impaler! that returns the result that I was looking for. :-)